# MacBook Pro Retina & Dell U2711 with miniDP to DP still no res higher than 1080p

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I bought an external monitor, the Dell u2711 due to the res and wanting to get the most out of my laptop.

Initially I used a mini dp adapter with dvi, hdmi and dp on and it wouldn't work, kept staying in power saver mode so I bought a single cable with minidp on one end and dp on the other.  Plugged it in and voila, it works.  Then I checked the resolution and have two options.  720p or 1080p.  I had more options using HDMI but I want 2560x1440.  That's why I bought it.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: It's great that you found the answer yourself. As this site works better if the question and the answer are separated I've removed it from your question again. Can you please put it in as an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added as requested: the solution was to hard rest the monitor by pulling the power and them power cycling the laptop. All is perfect now:)

Comment: Please, @SteveGreen, I have the same problem, you seemed to have. I have a Dell u2711 monitor as well and bought DP to miniDP cable, plugged it in and the monitor goes in power save mode. Could you describe once more exactly what you did to make it work? I don't understand this "power cycling the laptop." Best Cathrine la Cour

Comment: Hi @CathrinelaCour - I think Steve is referring to ensuring that you use a single cable without adapters, connecting it to the machine whilst it is turned off then turning the machine on, rather than connecting it with the machine already running.

Comment: Hi there. Stuffe is right. One of the adapters I had was faulty which didn't help. I used a cheap cable from eBay that worked perfectly. Occasionally I'll lose the resolution settings but that's a simple fix (reset pram after deleting a couple of preference files) - I can send the link of the cable when I get home.